# close opened connection using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Am using the below code in a class file and access this function for open the connection it return true. I want to close this connection state .I can't do this. please help me to do this.

```
common.cs
=========
 public static bool DBConnectionStatus()
        {
            try
            {
                string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|db_gym.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=gym_admin";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    return (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open);
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


protected void btn_general_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bool state = common.DBConnectionStatus();
                if(state == true)
                {
                // Some operation
                }
                // I want to close this connection

            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: In your current code the connection is closed and disposed because of your using statement. Bring the conn to a memberfield of the class or have DbConnectionStatus return the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `using` statement is translated into three parts: acquisition, usage, and disposal.

```
   using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
       conn.Open();
       return (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open);
     //connection is automatically closed and disposed here
    }
```

More information at [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2110618 Instead of checking the connection status, I would recommend you to use `using` each time you need to access your database.

Comment: Hmm, so it returns true to indicate that the connection was open/is openable? When the function return the connection is closed. 'Some operation' as indicated by the OP doesn't need an open connection?

Comment: @rene I think OP is just testing, that's why I suggested him to use `using` statement only instead of getting the status from a function.

Comment: I hope that knowledge survives time when the maintenance crew steps in :-)

Answer (score 0):

You better give back an open connection because you need that in an OleDbCommand. You coukd hide the connection as well in the Common class if you like but if you keep it in the using statement there is no open connection when you get status so basically if true is returned your connection in reality is closed (and Disposed). Refactor to something like this:

```
public OleDbConnection GetOpenConnection()
{
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|db_gym.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=gym_admin";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
 }


protected void btn_general_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using(OleDbConnection  openConnection = common.GetOpenConnection())
        {
           // I want to close this connection
           openConnection.Close(); // close asap
        }  // dispose
     }
     catch (Exception e1)
     {
     }
}
```